# How to get friends info that requires permission like B'day using facebook graph api

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm having android Button for Login.

below is the onclick listener of that button.

```
btnLoginFB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@
Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    Session s = new Session(Startup.this);
    Session.setActiveSession(s);
    Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(Startup.this);

    List < String > permissions = new ArrayList < String > ();
    permissions.add("friends_birthday");
    permissions.add("friends_location");
    request.setPermissions(permissions);

    request.setCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @
        Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

            if (session.isOpened()) {

                Request.newMyFriendsRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {

                    @
                    Override
                    public void onCompleted(List < GraphUser > users, Response response) {

                        if (users != null) {


                            for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
                                String frndLoc = "empty";

                                try {
                                    users.get(i).getLocation().getProperty("name");
                                    frndLoc = "" + users.get(i).getLocation().getProperty("name");
                                } catch (Exception e) {}

                                Toast.makeText(Startup.this, users.get(i).getBirthday() + " - " +
                                    users.get(i).getName() + "\n" +
                                    frndLoc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }).executeAsync();


            } // end of if (session.isOpened())
        } // end of call
    });
    s.openForRead(request);
}
});
```

The problem is I'm getting null for both B'day and Location of friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
Request friendRequest = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(activeSession, new GraphUserListCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(final List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {


                            ArrayList<String> o = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (GraphUser u : users) {
                                o.add(u.getInnerJSONObject().toString());
                            }
                            getSherlockActivity().startService(
                                    new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), InsertInDBService.class).putExtra("fbdata", o));

                        }

                    }
                });
```

Parse the reponse

```
int count = users.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                String name = "", id = "", photoUrl = "";
                String birthday = "", location = "";
                String website = "";
                JSONObject o = null;
                try {
                    o = new JSONObject(users.get(i));
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }
                try {
                    id = o.getString("id");
                    name = o.getString("name");
                    photoUrl = o.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    dbFacebookMain.deleteFACEBOOK();
                }

                try {
                    location = o.getJSONObject("location").getString("name");
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }
                try {
                    birthday = o.getString("birthday");
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }
                try {
                    website = o.getString("website");
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }
```

Comment: I've checked the JSON response returned it gives only ID and Name feild. NO values for birthday and location in response.

Comment: set the permission on login button `button.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("friends_interests", "friends_website", "friends_photos",
    "friends_about_me", "friends_birthday", "friends_likes", "friends_location"));`

Comment: I'm using Android's button. I've mentioned permissions on obj of Session.OpenRequest.

Comment: May be your friends hide it from their profile. The code is working fine for me.

Comment: Hey I'm done with the solution. Thnx for the helping.

Comment: Glad that you find the solution. If my answer helped you then up vote and accept it :)